# Alternatives to slow SMTP services like Mailgun

Tags: node.js, angular, email, smtp

I am using Mailgun for sending emails to customers for account verification and password reset. Unfortunately Mailgun seems to be a very bad option. Even during development, at times it takes 20 minutes to get the email. This is not acceptable for password reset as the token has a specific timeout. I need to find a solution that is reliable and the customer immediately gets their password reset token sent to them. I have little experience with this kind of thing and would appreciate any advice.

Not sure if it matters but we are using nodejs as a backend.

Thanks.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26012969/mailgun-messages-accepted-but-taking-long-time-to-be-delivered-or-not-being

Answer (score 0):

I use sendgrid all the time. They are pretty reliable.

Comment: Thanks you for the input.

Answer (score 0):

I had issues with Mailgun as well.  Have you tried [sendmail](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sendmail)?  I don't know how well it might work for a production environment, but it works really well in our testing environment.

Comment: We are currently correcting some things that we noticed. Mailgun was evidently showing warnings that our emails were being labeled as spam. This is not my job but it seems that when constructing email templates there is a standard that is somehow used to identify possible spam. Our Dev Ops guy is currently reviewing the guidelines so we can construct the templates to be seen as legit emails. I'll update this after we see the results. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I can't imagine having to wait 20 minutes for a password reset email! As the end-user then would drive me crazy. I'm wondering if they are throttling your emails or something.

But anyway, if you're still looking for an alternative, here are some of the top SMTP services that you could try.

1. SocketLabs.com: disclaimer - I work for SocketLabs, so I'm a little bias with that opinion :)
2. Sendgrid
3. Sparkpost
4. AWS

Comment: Thank you. I tried several of them and was having to same issue. We are currently researching to see why mailgun has classified our emails as SPAM.